# Change the default value of a settingsvalue

Tags: c#, settings

id didnt find anything on Stackoverflow or on the internet, im sorry if this question was already posted (or if its simply impossible).

Is there a way to change the default value of a *.settigs-property, for example if i have the setting "USER"

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("TESTUSER")]
        public string SQLServer {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["USER"]));
            }
            set {
                this["USER"] = value;
            }
        }
```

would there be a way to change (at runtime) the DefaultSettingValueAttribute ("TESTUSER") to another value (i.e: "John Doe").

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of doing what you want to do?

Comment: I want to achieve that if the programm calls XXX.Properties.Settings.Default.Reset() Settings that were declared by the user will be loaded and not "my" devdefaultsettings. This programm is used to save serverconnectionstrings, so if the new connectionstring doesnt work (for any reason) you could just call settings.Default.Reset() and you will get your earlier, working, settings back. At the moment im saving the earlier connectionstrings in an own file, but that seems not the be the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `Properties` property of the `ApplicationSettingsBase` class:

```
public override SettingsPropertyCollection Properties
{
    get
    {
        var properties = base.Properties;
        properties["SQLServer"].DefaultValue = 
            String.Format("John Doe {0}", DateTime.Now);
        return properties;
    }
}
```